# Turning on/off setInterval locating - using React.js

Tags: react.js, google-maps

I work with the `GoogleMaps` API, using `React.js`.

Inside the `GoogleMap` component:

- I have a component called `UserLocationTimer`, which activates
  `setInterval` within `useEffect` and samples the user's location every 2
  seconds, centering the map accordingly. In addition, returns the
  `UserLocation` component that displays the marker of the user's
  location on the map.
- In case the user drags the map, I catch the event `isDragged`, and return only the `UserLocation` component that displays the
  marker of the user's location on the map.

It works fine, however, how would you optimize this code?
Is there a more efficient way to catch the dragging event and stopping the timer interval from the parent, instead using conditional rendering?

```
  <GoogleMap
    . . .
    onDrag={(map) => {
      setIsDragged(true);
    }}
    onDragEnd={(map) => {
      setIsDragged(true);
    }}

  >
    . . .

    {!isDragged && (
      <UserLocationTimer
        userLocation={userLocation}
        setUserLocation={setUserLocation}
        panTo={panTo}
      ></UserLocationTimer>
    )}

    {isDragged && (
      <UserLocation userLocation={userLocation}></UserLocation>
    )}

  </GoogleMap>
```

- 

```
export const UserLocationTimer = (props) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer(new Date());
      locateMe();
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  function locateMe() {
    // locating using geolocation...
  }

  return (
    <>
      {timer && <UserLocation userLocation={props.userLocation}></UserLocation>}
    </>
  );
};
```

- 

```
export const UserLocation = (props) => {

  if (props.userLocation)
    return (
      <>
        <Marker
          position={{
            lat: props.userLocation.lat,
            lng: props.userLocation.lng,
          }}
          icon={{
            url: userLocationIcon,
            scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(30, 30),
            origin: new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 15),
          }}
        />
      </>
    );
  else return null;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, please [edit] the title of this question so that it only states the task that is accomplished by the code.

Comment: You've misunderstood what I meant, your title should only state the task accomplished by your code. Any questions you have belong to the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typo?** I think you meant to set `isDragged` to `false` when dragging finishes:

```
onDragEnd={() => {
  setIsDragged(false);
}}
```

Note that you don't need to declare parameter you don't use (and probably shouldn't, to make the code easier to read).

**Concise props** When you have variables that you want to pass as props of the same name, you can make things a bit concise by using shorthand property names and spreading the object into props. For example:

```
<UserLocationTimer
  userLocation={userLocation}
  setUserLocation={setUserLocation}
  panTo={panTo}
></UserLocationTimer>
```

can be

```
<UserLocationTimer {...{userLocation, setUserLocation, panTo}} />
```

(it has no children, so it can be made self-closing)

Listing fewer identifiers while writing code means less chance of typos, and helps enforce consistent names for things.

**Marker position props** Rather than listing out the `lat` and `lng` properties of `userLocation`, you can pass the plain object itself to `position`:

```
<Marker position={props.userLocation}
```

**Return early instead of long if/else blocks** - if one sees `if` followed by a long block of code, followed by an `else`, keeping track of what condition the `else` is corresponding to can be harder to recognize at a glance than it needs to be. Consider returning the short branch first instead. See below.

**JSX fragments are only needed when enclosing 2 or more tags** - if a fragment only has one child tag, it can be removed completely, like this:

```
export const UserLocation = ({ userLocation }) => (
  if (!userLocation) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Marker
      // ...
```

The same thing applies to the JSX returned by `UserLocationTimer`, but there's a better approach:

**Consolidate `UserLocation`** Since `UserLocation` is being rendered regardless, I think conditionally putting it inside `UserLocationTimer` isn't the right way to go. I'd remove the timer component completely, and implement its logic in the parent component instead, while unconditionally rendering `UserLocation`.

```
const intervalRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  if (isDragged) {
    const intervalId = setInterval(locateMe, 2000);
    // Cleanup will run on dismount and when isDragged goes to false
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, [isDragged]);

// ...

<GoogleMap
  onDrag={() => {
    setIsDragged(true);
  }}
  onDragEnd={() => {
    setIsDragged(false);
  }}
>
  . . .
  <UserLocation {...{userLocation}} />
</GoogleMap>
```

**Naming** The name `UserLocation` is very similar to `userLocation`, but one is a *component*, while the other holds *data*. Maybe rename them so that they're more distinct - perhaps `UserLocationMarker` and `userLocationCoords`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, very very enlightening